# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.orc.storage.ql.exec.vector.VectorizedRowBatch appears in flink query hive

Tags: java, hive, apache-flink, flink-sql

1. Software version:

- flink 1.11
- hive1.2.1
- hadoop2.7.1

2. Use flink run jar to run the submission program with the following exceptions

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:116)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:179)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:386)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor$$Lambda$98/618592213.apply(Unknown Source)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/orc/storage/ql/exec/vector/VectorizedRowBatch
    at org.apache.flink.orc.nohive.OrcNoHiveSplitReaderUtil.genPartColumnarRowReader(OrcNoHiveSplitReaderUtil.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.connectors.hive.read.HiveVectorizedOrcSplitReader.<init>(HiveVectorizedOrcSplitReader.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.connectors.hive.read.HiveTableInputFormat.open(HiveTableInputFormat.java:137)
    at org.apache.flink.connectors.hive.read.HiveTableInputFormat.open(HiveTableInputFormat.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.InputFormatSourceFunction.run(InputFormatSourceFunction.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:213)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.orc.storage.ql.exec.vector.VectorizedRowBatch
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:48)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

3. I added the following dependencies in maven

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-storage-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The program still reports an error, I don’t quite clear what caused it!

4. My pom configuration is as follows

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.credit.analyze</groupId>
    <artifactId>fast-analyze</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Fast Analyze Job</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.11.0</flink.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.version>2.12.1</log4j.version>
        <hive.version>1.2.1</hive.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.7.1</hadoop.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.16</mysql.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- or.. (for the new Blink planner) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-jdbc_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.orc</groupId>
            <artifactId>orc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>







        <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
        <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.credit.analyze.job.batch.market.channel.MarketMonitorHiveJob</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving some warnings. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>shade</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

5. I have added the following jar package in the flink lib directory

```
flink-sql-connector-hive-1.2.2
hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar
hive-exec-1.2.1.jar
libfb303-0.9.2.jar 
orc-core-1.4.3-nohive.jar
aircompressor-0.8.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. Need to add the following dependencies in pom.xml

```xml
<!-- flink orc nohive -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-orc-nohive_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly indicates, make sure that your have proper `orc-core` jar imported as dependency in case,

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.orc.storage.ql.exec.vector.VectorizedRowBatch
```

you should add the following artifact,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.orc</groupId>
    <artifactId>orc-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added the dependency and still couldn’t find the class. I updated my question content and added my pom.xml configuration

Comment: could you please add the lib ```orc-core``` manually inside ```Flink-1.11.1/lib``` and restart Flink and try it out?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have solved the problem and responded to this question

Comment: That's really nice to hear that.